# PPM modulation and demodulation

Tags: software-defined-radio

What is the procedure for modulating and demodulating the PPM signal in the samples received by SDR? The samples are in IQ format.

I want to play with the ADS-B system in Python (on the desktop of course, without transmitting to space) and I have no idea how to bite on the modulation and demodulation of these signals.

Comment: in ADS-B Mode-S, only the replies are PPM-modulated, the interrogations are DPSK. (So that you don't wonder that you can't see when the transponder are asked to transmit something; you only see their responses).

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just want to send and receive in ADS-B, nothing more. A simple system - the transmitter sends a message and the receiver receives it.

Comment: But what do you want to send and receive - interrogations or replies?

Comment: I want to use one SDR to transmit an ADS-B message with virtual values for coordinates, altitude, velocity, etc. and use the other SDR to receive and decode that message.

Comment: Ah these messages are replies! At home I have a link to a presentation stored somewhere that I can give you. I'm currently underway, else I'd help you out with pretty and relatively explanatory pictures.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20110717003442if_/http://adsb.tc.faa.gov/WG3_Meetings/Meeting8/Squitter-Lon.pdf is a somewhat superficial intro into how the different messages types in ADS-B are modulated. I gather you want to receive and transmit Mode-S, and slides 27ff give you an idea of how to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much!